# Reading Local HTML File in Python

Tags: python, html

I've been reviewing examples of how to read in HTML from websites using XPass and lxml. For some reason when I try with a local file I keep running into this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
```

This is the code

```
with open(r'H:\Python\Project\File','r') as f:
    file = f.read()
f.close()

tree = html.fromstring(file.content)
```

Comment: `file` is string already, change to `tree = html.fromstring(file)` , `with open` will close the file `f ` automatically, no need to re-close, remove `f.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your code.  It looks like you are modifying code that is parsing html from an http/https request.  In that case using `.content()` extracts the bytes from the response object.

However, when reading from a file, you are already reading in the contents of the file in your `with` context.  Also, you don't need to use `.close()`, the context manager takes care of that for you.

Try this:

```
with open(r'H:\Python\Project\File','r') as f:
    tree = html.fromstring(f.read())
```

Comment: thank you, this worked great! And is much more consise

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding='utf-8'

```
f1 = open(new_file + '.html', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
```